# How to measure my Maximum Heart Rate with a stationary bike and a heart monitor?

Tags: bicycling, heart-rate-monitor

I've just bought a heart monitor. It looks like the fundamental number for my training is my **Maximum Heart Rate (MRH or Max HR)**. This number changes if you are cycling or running.

I've seen protocols to measure it running or cycling outdoor. I believe I'll get a more precise measurement if I do it in cycling indoor.

Does anybody here can give me a protocol to measure my MHR it in a stationary bike?

Comment: I find that following various protocols isn't the most effective way. What's worked best for me is simply doing racing on zwift - there's nothing quite as motivating as trying to catch someone up in a race and I've scored higher heart rates doing this than anything else (inc FTP/ramp tests / very hard workouts etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this [article](http://www.maxworkouts.com/articles/entry/is-the-maximum-heart-rate-formula-sabotaging-your-workout-and-your-results), I've found this protocol:

1. Warm up thoroughly.  I suggest spending about 5 minutes until you break a light sweat.
2. Run or Bike for 4 minutes.  You should be too out of breath to talk.
3. Active rest - walking or easy cycling for 3 minutes.
4. Run or Bike for 4 minutes.  You should be too out of breath to talk.
5. Active rest - walking or easy cycling for 3 minutes.
6. Run or Bike for 2 minutes at which point run or bike as fast as you can until you reach exhaustion and can’t continue.
7. Immediately take your heart rate.  This is your MAX HR

I'm still leaving the answer unmarked to see if someone gives me a better answer. I'll choose any one that improves this one (also  marked as a community wiki).

Some doubts: how much time before to eat? At what time of the day? Should I set any resistance on the bike?

Comment: We don't know if he has any history of disease or exercise. This protocol may be harmful for him.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I do not suggest you to try to get your MHR alone at home. Here is the list of protocols including cycle ergometer protocols [in the link here](http://www.topendsports.com/testing/aerobic.htm)

To stay on the safe side you may try this formula.
You may try karvonen method to calculate you THR
For you max HR you can use 220-age formula then
Target Heart Rate = ((max HR − resting HR) × %Intensity) + resting HR

If you insist on getting your MHR you need to go to exercise physiology lab where there is a physician, ECG and defibrillator ,just in case.

BE CAREFUL

Comment: 220-age is one of the worst myths in exercise science.

Comment: Yes I agree with you, but it works :-)

Comment: No, actually it doesn't. It's a gross generalization and gives false impressions. Promoting it in any way degrades the exercise kinesiology field.

Comment: Actually, It does not. If you check the MHR formulas, they are more or less same.By the way not kinesiology , physiology.

Comment: I will grant it also falls into physiology, but exercise prescription, exercise testing and the like are a large part of the kinesiology field, especially if you fall into the clinical and research side of things. And "more or less" gives an unacceptable range of heart rates.

Comment: kinesiology  :-)

Comment: I really did not get how measuring MHR fall into kinesiology. Kinesiology, also known as human kinetics, is the scientific study of human movement. Kinesiology addresses physiological, mechanical, and psychological mechanisms. Applications of kinesiology to human health include biomechanics and orthopedics; strength and conditioning; sport psychology; methods of rehabilitation, such as physical and occupational therapy; and sport and exercise.(you can read the rest on WİKİ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinesiology). Measuring MHR is directly related to physiology.

Comment: Thank you for the enlightening wiki entry. I have a degree in exercise kinesiology, which included anatomy, physiology, EKG and stress test training among other areas. Designed to be used in clinical and research settings. You need to expand your worldview. (or if it makes you happy, you can refer to it as exercise physiology, since it's now been subclassified as a field of kinesiology).

Comment: Congrats. very nice CV. Biased attacks does not help anybody. I really want to see what you did with your degree and if it is ok for you I want to read your articles published in PubMed. By the way, all the sub areas you mentioned are under exercise science not exercise kinesiology and exercsie physiology is under exercise science, at least it is classified like this in USA :-)

Comment: So if I dont have published studies my knowledge is worthless? Good to know I wasted my time. Thank you for the edification.

Comment: I didn't mean that. It would not be kind to have an argument like that. Sure your degree and your knowledge is valuable. I just wanted to see what you studied so far and how you used your degree. Since we all talk about science articles or books are the best indicators of them otherwise your knowledge can be interpreted as bro-science like you said before. I really don't want to discuss these kind of things here but I just try to understand your biased attacks to me on every comment or question I answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37064/discussion-between-johnp-and-bantandor).

Comment: https://www.asep.org/asep/asep/Robergs2.pdf    THE SURPRISING HISTORY OF THE “HRmax=220-age” EQUATION

Comment: From your linked article since you posted it here: Despite the acceptance of this formula, research spanning more than two decades reveals the large error inherent in the estimation of HRmax 
(Sxy=7 - 11 b/min).  Ironically, inquiry into the history of this formula reveals that it was not developed from original research, but resulted from observation based on data from approximately 11 references consisting of published research or unpublished scientific compilations.  Consequently, the formula HRmax=220 age has **no 
scientific merit for use in exercise physiology and related fields**

Comment: As I expected you didn't get it.  If you look at the first comments we have: 220-age is one of the worst myths in exercise science. – JohnP yesterday
     
Yes I agree with you, but it works :-) – bantandor yesterday

Comment: I am not saying it is scientificly proven. I had read this article long time ago I am aweare of the issue. The thing is it works. When you prescribe an exercise to a person who has not taken any math class you can't give other  formula except 220-age. If you check the other regression formulas in the article they are different than each other and no different than 220-age. MHR are more or less off from each other. There is no perfect formula. If there is you can share with us with the reasons. IT WORKS :-)